# sh error trying to mount: command not found

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, sudo, mount

I'm trying to make a script to mount a disk when runned. The script is

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=$(python /home/pi/prova.py 2>1&)
sudo mount $PATH /media/Drive1
```

where path in our case is /dev/sda1 (checked using echo).

The error reported is
   **./script.sh: line3: sudo: command not found**

the script is added to /etc/sudoers using line

```
 pi ALL=NOPASSWD: /home/pi/script.sh
```

The error is the same both adding and removing the sudo before mount command.

Any idea ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You're replacing your search path by using the variable `PATH`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use all-upper-case variable names for regular shell variables. This avoids overwriting environment variables and shell builtins (such as `PATH`, used by the shell to determine where it looks for external commands) by mistake.

Thus, a corrected implementation of this script may be:

```
#!/bin/bash
path=$(python /home/pi/prova.py 2>1&)
sudo mount "$path" /media/Drive1
```